# Gets all polygons from a json file

Tags: json, ruby, coordinates

I have a json file, with the coordinates of several polygons. What I want to do is automate the getting the coordinates but saving them separately by polygons. In the file that I currently use, I have 2 polygons:

> {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[
> [[[0.03990083369766674,41.65117297365802],[0.03986585098450487,41.6511738730363],[0.0398193071116094,41.65118861345209],[0.03978640897789055,41.651211227828185],[0.039785212880236676,41.65121205009294],[0.039761889395081365,41.65124414021116],[0.03975127958141444,41.65127097990489],[0.03973309671778063,41.65131697476312],[0.039706482497244025,41.651425988964064],[0.03969658765996025,41.65146652049745],[0.039683272167788275,41.65150292059053],[0.03968380609505212,41.65151410540278],[0.03968455879000179,41.6515298809837],[0.03969278143750318,41.65153853529924],[0.03969588944738445,41.651541805918015],[0.03971376972429572,41.65156062329174],[0.039752407785648564,41.65158215221135],[0.03979465677110295,41.65160350427274],[0.03988602119749911,41.651632606242316],[0.03992955596697664,41.65164948823451],[0.03993958742929026,41.65165619711021],[0.039968351608118506,41.651675434417314],[0.03999355934521909,41.651701840766634],[0.04000585559790465,41.65173745966629],[0.04000155651951174,41.65177364266802],[0.03998752269819514,41.65181002432095],[0.03993384247251406,41.65191499844431],[0.0399064931590255,41.65198778102845],[0.03987869457550017,41.65209657478536],[0.03987154648804941,41.65213727647139],[0.03986267424301351,41.65216458136081],[0.039847923768933036,41.65220997439829],[0.03980755819723356,41.65227854926681],[0.03978735697119576,41.65231062932676],[0.0397695957173166,41.65234709479867],[0.039757844288369676,41.65238344543852],[0.03975297859328857,41.65242411611149],[0.03975461138812371,41.65245838049552],[0.039754692692589313,41.652460093756645],[0.03976241996958375,41.65249586520693],[0.039775312175620324,41.65253159055675],[0.039792208417040606,41.65257165102716],[0.0398126778639959,41.65260712072893],[0.03984532034965278,41.652678297340344],[0.039888420936520154,41.652749203216246],[0.039899750755712435,41.652784978019326],[0.03990246230155005,41.65282539304425],[0.03990100971764384,41.65284035977143],[0.03989973315371473,41.652853510978275],[0.03989900644266644,41.65286150731441],[0.03988340855812481,41.65289793925871],[0.03982299431103434,41.65300310029855],[0.03980279308499652,41.653035180358444],[0.039796679324458795,41.65304764676378],[0.03978491196989489,41.653071643315826],[0.0397440929372068,41.65317631904341],[0.0397286140756973,41.65321275350229],[0.03970857042944851,41.65324925082547],[0.03966616386420511,41.6533061086308],[0.03966059408921564,41.6533135760688],[0.03962721818698753,41.653337031149846],[0.039608159414420085,41.65335700606448],[0.03959644067489746,41.653369288906106],[0.039574675385634625,41.65340141925745],[0.03955691413175548,41.653437884729385],[0.03954504200339567,41.653474232016464],[0.03952742659464041,41.65350945529025],[0.03952465972823856,41.65351498818487],[0.03951080444147017,41.653542693729264],[0.03949758031204822,41.6535615806728],[0.03948831998487233,41.6535748056404],[0.03938851917243118,41.65370353659338],[0.039367413538987255,41.65375064205381],[0.039358610025561444,41.653770290912405],[0.039341569615398024,41.653808324638504],[0.03932925156976292,41.65384916294957],[0.039294849722525456,41.653976004621455],[0.03927882436089661,41.65403509285139],[0.03927713624549725,41.654056445750996],[0.03927596780812548,41.65407122304717],[0.039281407663608055,41.65410711603502],[0.039310323554892744,41.654178376465495],[0.03936399288409906,41.65425614795873],[0.039382605739391195,41.65428311924833],[0.03939218541709694,41.654297000518994],[0.0394054858218423,41.65431627386832],[0.03942630395599031,41.65434644117781],[0.039450928312595376,41.6544222747749],[0.03945708817360331,41.65445818620299],[0.039456164487818746,41.654516564485675],[0.03945594907289441,41.654530202681144],[0.039453803305554584,41.65455188918051],[0.03945192324456115,41.65457089514709],[0.03943704788011598,41.65460725500702],[0.03941627919919963,41.65464382357635],[0.03934394253232732,41.654732627331185],[0.0393319027658941,41.654747407980096],[0.039311307590383746,41.65477269199252],[0.03926260956824479,41.6548369987957],[0.03925610688737672,41.65484747114613],[0.03921995489865273,41.65490569352545],[0.03921109941742416,41.65492864736862],[0.0392059194009554,41.6549420751783],[0.03919861708647711,41.65497826991475],[0.03919375139139601,41.65501894058772],[0.039193012107492216,41.655039557556165],[0.03919245806365955,41.655055020492085],[0.03919789791914211,41.655090913479995],[0.03921464077172523,41.65512646783898],[0.03923784355746767,41.65515732497917],[0.03926289874392143,41.65517922521707],[0.03928896814071942,41.655192054558825],[0.03933606186649572,41.65518633390957],[0.0394175440284636,41.655148178645845],[0.039442782778607764,41.65513278192702],[0.03945621058828894,41.65512459029256],[0.039527098862206865,41.65506869053877],[0.039586379037730636,41.65501163156773],[0.039623324792732284,41.654976069665025],[0.039725422246779336,41.654896838882365],[0.03976381052740279,41.654868829913084],[0.03980034640731491,41.65485428311925],[0.039848573366467556,41.654835081854316],[0.039941219385935034,41.654810092046716],[0.039994916375423455,41.6547901758054],[0.04003271457002846,41.654776157071524],[0.04003523752303347,41.65477534486507],[0.04007854095196967,41.65476139737734],[0.04011864668465535,41.654737845904435],[0.040155591601466624,41.654709888902886],[0.040182720470888646,41.654686606489065],[0.040188089918380375,41.654681998118434],[0.040242230310573,41.65462206415444],[0.04027888772808837,41.654571541391874],[0.040315545145603725,41.6545210177911],[0.04037410196284068,41.65445642432684],[0.04040103721028788,41.65442415735046],[0.040431813884187574,41.654391899594174],[0.04046347317254383,41.65436398701678],[0.04046785858454457,41.65436054037798],[0.04047288018303395,41.65435659333954],[0.040498973887352574,41.65433608282126],[0.04050050609934366,41.65433434776722],[0.04052434842433622,41.65430734714093],[0.040555966641364495,41.65427153964842],[0.04057773193062733,41.65423940929708],[0.04060973320065338,41.65417113617707],[0.04065305339339694,41.65410239115596],[0.04065650087037687,41.6540996050112],[0.04068771927060004,41.65407437631933],[0.04072866319365282,41.65405084580112],[0.040770455365357124,41.654027156026785],[0.040860539036872326,41.65399777745441],[0.040907804591673896,41.653983054640634],[0.04095089763482795,41.65397290750806],[0.04100058555979046,41.6539760792204],[0.04104998095631486,41.65398824890633],[0.04109435643073061,41.65400515185328],[0.04114391192161512,41.65403052052292],[0.04116956473780064,41.65404365328962],[0.04119017248616651,41.65406561806819],[0.04119417065421764,41.6541015638621],[0.04119530388759398,41.65412534919008],[0.04119588475351839,41.65413754066901],[0.04120276964919386,41.65417338085089],[0.04122281245725229,41.65419983413889],[0.04124421732465728,41.654211061698874],[0.04126361975527523,41.654221238168105],[0.04131172601501501,41.654237967609646],[0.04136353875255816,41.65424896382905],[0.04138485477178423,41.65425348754249],[0.04140638955869612,41.654258057356344],[0.04145406834134867,41.65426576954596],[0.04160685871060841,41.654275199187566],[0.04165954987165629,41.65427835748889],[0.04181220445407655,41.65426977106674],[0.041937059614781114,41.65426650044793],[0.04196128164000998,41.654265865937816],[0.04198126661293308,41.65426063060079],[0.04198913302952844,41.65425856949068],[0.04198995948523041,41.654258353237566],[0.04199706314859171,41.65425649161676],[0.04201822074983839,41.654250948663844],[0.04202009075254742,41.65425045916069],[0.04202343094116037,41.65424958408994],[0.042057054109546785,41.65424077554738],[0.042151707594943494,41.65421124274798],[0.04219497246712282,41.65419209345086],[0.04220322026033522,41.65418708861617],[0.04227241455152121,41.65414509695515],[0.04227500791251706,41.65414385391884],[0.042302370637051494,41.65413073875416],[0.042353914315486796,41.6541248613633],[0.042403152132222184,41.65413261378603],[0.042413530605347784,41.654134562578605],[0.042414217083258446,41.65413469165995],[0.04243573091541116,41.65413873089932],[0.042487086839204234,41.6541483734413],[0.04250871131248541,41.654161268161914],[0.04251341356044492,41.65417922052319],[0.04249180752735182,41.65421576813779],[0.04243910882259064,41.654275740658534],[0.042402066675696765,41.6543058694113],[0.04224077202697229,41.65443706045298],[0.042230817678172446,41.654445157371924],[0.042212416885043194,41.65446012326092],[0.042203314137656336,41.654467526996456],[0.042190945800599206,41.654477586957256],[0.04216446569052133,41.65449912509689],[0.042158375399313885,41.65450340238232],[0.04212451502305359,41.65452718519583],[0.04208356690904897,41.65455080623855],[0.04195181511800379,41.65460378908983],[0.04190542295756477,41.65462303729345],[0.04185803335058887,41.654637846440835],[0.04181464861718705,41.65465699238521],[0.0416459468801884,41.6547380219244],[0.041602715535623766,41.654761673980175],[0.041584732161297336,41.6547697449152],[0.0415343996679425,41.65479233414561],[0.041517508455664424,41.65479991473927],[0.041206645441451396,41.65492519234792],[0.041072091580008956,41.654967805108015],[0.041067007117242045,41.654969415271694],[0.04098074475561051,41.65500777505386],[0.0409415702524227,41.655031294675524],[0.040926787088917914,41.655043202846116],[0.04091264346466323,41.65505459552958],[0.04090137650974849,41.65507725684432],[0.04089677233006193,41.655086517171526],[0.04089737917988772,41.65510847356819],[0.04089776642383733,41.65512247553826],[0.040903428399767176,41.65513149865757],[0.04091724010063649,41.65515350702202],[0.04094500934749897,41.655184301297936],[0.04096908636579433,41.65521968382788],[0.04098133567981932,41.65523302865674],[0.04105383830838432,41.65531201552599],[0.04109895139032312,41.655378379248276],[0.04112916228572502,41.65541355977439],[0.04115775631190874,41.65544364997035],[0.04118758834526468,41.65547504355237],[0.04120909547189447,41.65548727945534],[0.041225389892631165,41.65549654984082],[0.04127064379055165,41.655517888491175],[0.04131000940114316,41.65553934616457],[0.041343394523465304,41.655565511953284],[0.04137345119183965,41.65559618552976],[0.04137836801653314,41.65560232024504],[0.04139821468804566,41.65562708290304],[0.04142181226145102,41.65566441590201],[0.04177131668977836,41.6555764746451],[0.04208765141070791,41.65549688008781],[0.04280846076062087,41.655315512456184],[0.04502639796742188,41.65475740088567],[0.04503264248565688,41.65475582927874],[0.04491913726071341,41.65471054688234],[0.04481832056154731,41.65463496222779],[0.04490633893199795,41.65458509157733],[0.04516969080163186,41.654501499690184],[0.0454428671005587,41.654456392475595],[0.04567295370909296,41.65444145676145],[0.04576299295651871,41.65449938493592],[0.04582947067272489,41.65455530648262],[0.04584204604280269,41.65455214147582],[0.04669402212688459,41.6543377323799],[0.04674658839756776,41.65432450405953],[0.04758604107937462,41.6541131971062],[0.04747183177452276,41.65406386792671],[0.04745190379854463,41.6540552605498],[0.04730123069815222,41.653990180935125],[0.04693486523240001,41.653832617071714],[0.04660293514149995,41.653688814617794],[0.046272875891499275,41.65354614120625],[0.04589455364016018,41.65338232192815],[0.04559773953469034,41.65325319954027],[0.04547678028281212,41.65320111690542],[0.04547537212299538,41.65320051089381],[0.04545764355854056,41.65319287749412],[0.04542093836417426,41.65317707257657],[0.0454185159940133,41.65317602902954],[0.04540317375753365,41.653169423251285],[0.04538960261729971,41.653163579388035],[0.04530522534580381,41.65312724886476],[0.045198634353198666,41.65308073013756],[0.044926965120551894,41.65296216727194],[0.044682048409852286,41.65285887288209],[0.044474430332298885,41.65278022380352],[0.04404397599288677,41.65262487360093],[0.043744324613024264,41.65251593567527],[0.04336616161785493,41.652380391072825],[0.04304298726352973,41.652263371315655],[0.04280758401349688,41.652177968937366],[0.042621828455288904,41.6521115809075],[0.042493676691870486,41.65206577967129],[0.04213919341276249,41.651937684904794],[0.04190932641010441,41.65185728652298],[0.04175594344025513,41.65180033484029],[0.041663035905393116,41.651765838277555],[0.04139794143798598,41.65166988811163],[0.041386050031247734,41.65166558400412],[0.04132406082445745,41.65164317163189],[0.04112134448417094,41.651569877751626],[0.041083383680634716,41.65155590847098],[0.040914122032470836,41.65149362003021],[0.04079188789304423,41.65144863770598],[0.04053546785774635,41.651355575105924],[0.04031697006922782,41.65127609705709],[0.040218658721069014,41.65124693138503],[0.040136785962390065,41.65122264230462],[0.04003391569682453,41.65119818390971],[0.03995920862759403,41.6511804218176],[0.03990083369766674,41.65117297365802]]],

Here starts second polygon

> [[[0.04758604107937462,41.6541131971062],[0.04674658839756776,41.65432450405953],[0.04669402212688459,41.6543377323799],[0.04584204604280269,41.65455214147582],[0.04582947067272489,41.65455530648262],[0.04595265951097963,41.65465893279591],[0.04610042744355961,41.65482261628716],[0.04614809197697591,41.654895094608236],[0.045911219379229505,41.654906380003325],[0.045561253108009875,41.65490780408874],[0.045443292901265184,41.65490303143281],[0.04522180361132643,41.654831294910224],[0.04503264248565688,41.65475582927874],[0.04502639796742188,41.65475740088567],[0.04280846076062087,41.655315512456184],[0.04208765141070791,41.65549688008781],[0.04177131668977836,41.6555764746451],[0.04142181226145102,41.65566441590201],[0.0414310650449136,41.65567905489678],[0.04144861088386839,41.65570681408536],[0.041465396484160214,41.655733370470756],[0.04149721083773439,41.655762378563],[0.04149725945277568,41.65576451343384],[0.04150375878088228,41.65605208229957],[0.041496843710353594,41.656059615954575],[0.041444482796310356,41.656116656485466],[0.04141456275296585,41.656135429435096],[0.04136614468640951,41.65614120624315],[0.04132706825149465,41.65614227074488],[0.04128124354593417,41.65612551029031],[0.04119501722648842,41.65607768063336],[0.04116495469078151,41.65606100567422],[0.04112186332400818,41.656039632658064],[0.04108033518226952,41.656018209350464],[0.041008348878970674,41.655995706453695],[0.040987399987125396,41.65598915767234],[0.040937129519857736,41.655972462596594],[0.040889723149074506,41.6559692598712],[0.04078962477905301,41.65596289884451],[0.04076305582079624,41.65595886211969],[0.04074718720076604,41.65595645148423],[0.0407389427603151,41.65595519838962],[0.04072028045179132,41.65594841407679],[0.04069311805475462,41.65593843793502],[0.04065432325180311,41.65591240206584],[0.04061847971713421,41.65588179722096],[0.040587874034069424,41.65585566495989],[0.04056173925842281,41.655836514824585],[0.04055220568118726,41.65582952934605],[0.04054751935884471,41.65582596871337],[0.04051785663994292,41.655803428936224],[0.0404244830712368,41.65571582798458],[0.04030450534027847,41.655592959335024],[0.04026526042909982,41.65557150501439],[0.04022374821297813,41.6555680935796],[0.0401938801374364,41.6555724697715],[0.0401866339817127,41.655573531758705],[0.04014841753011451,41.65559253940168],[0.04012136158325442,41.65562480302526],[0.04012063068125431,41.65562618352479],[0.040102036266150255,41.65566131878862],[0.040089356960466914,41.65569211977004],[0.04005893316471178,41.65576602552929],[0.040051750711455975,41.65580222361845],[0.04004544165256271,41.655842947097426],[0.040032126160390744,41.65587934802872],[0.040015807432133406,41.655915760694654],[0.03997528260426417,41.655979917461735],[0.039961119701631055,41.65598799258771],[0.03995049815329898,41.65599404851312],[0.039942853857150906,41.6559942496788],[0.03985371398798907,41.65599659745004],[0.03980228933258589,41.65600247651727],[0.03975174226249707,41.656012791287935],[0.03970507517561764,41.65602752835093],[0.03966397115820474,41.65604664160588],[0.03963545676010589,41.65606094616271],[0.039617866497061636,41.65608841114647],[0.03961844149565348,41.65616497480735],[0.03961414577002202,41.6562010672846],[0.039597102845287495,41.65623755119668],[0.03956400354588053,41.656265426893725],[0.03952633359440169,41.65629345430321],[0.039458177821080555,41.65634474149539],[0.0394236686854761,41.65637717275709],[0.03940910093689566,41.65639558109393],[0.03939817512546034,41.656409386927464],[0.03938098048826936,41.65644315007364],[0.039379568975691136,41.65644592113097],[0.03936309685859661,41.65647782684732],[0.03934677310119708,41.656514330037794],[0.03932541265788153,41.656568643097216],[0.039303821712215053,41.65662354288986],[0.03925695932698007,41.65669230970397],[0.03923426867555194,41.65671936732721],[0.039229902541929644,41.65672457332758],[0.03919439679797868,41.65678399683367],[0.039194100916779086,41.656824514956014],[0.039190951835569844,41.65686964228718],[0.03919596421396519,41.65689651886129],[0.03922662018845202,41.65692720836341],[0.039295667796323756,41.65696968449845],[0.03930393654429534,41.65697477063759],[0.03930853485664933,41.65697727682681],[0.03934330215488685,41.65699622831099],[0.039396235552950826,41.657026310125076],[0.0395476487754374,41.65711235707178],[0.03966764578477417,41.65719028782115],[0.03969654491225152,41.65721413098436],[0.039736377394877516,41.657246994752256],[0.03979621748156652,41.657291811953],[0.039811843864580615,41.65730351476691],[0.03987315665174465,41.65736489293292],[0.039900202540320305,41.65739576013138],[0.03990380759708926,41.65740158639261],[0.03994403067642632,41.65746659392292],[0.03996293773653732,41.65750211391611],[0.039985982104300384,41.657550193353785],[0.039997026100577475,41.65757323688334],[0.04004428075890426,41.65768459550276],[0.04005657533520909,41.657720304926954],[0.04006502261772887,41.65775609565563],[0.040096527679057574,41.6578678582828],[0.04011371812529672,41.657898920779616],[0.040169337085296936,41.657958161560174],[0.040171425855691785,41.65796038611745],[0.04020865827179899,41.657986472278054],[0.04022491162120769,41.65799241672411],[0.04025448381554984,41.6580032327326],[0.04025571427900875,41.65800344479476],[0.040299878529452,41.65801106729796],[0.04034742403983617,41.658000765100184],[0.04052384467192559,41.65793758817762],[0.040566616688169035,41.65792652238841],[0.04091163679803233,41.65783725930527],[0.0410018461981026,41.65780788324747],[0.0410316874515526,41.657801838218546],[0.04105311914104934,41.65779749723063],[0.04106175166364024,41.6577980143941],[0.04110581197847795,41.65780065553193],[0.04113990704804105,41.65780873820165],[0.04117413706625324,41.65783483693511],[0.041195893973612424,41.65786583656762],[0.04122952468571213,41.65789191937549],[0.041266762130961546,41.65791791417334],[0.04137407564366314,41.657976714065796],[0.041394564368996876,41.65798793994935],[0.041404999839067445,41.65799365808405],[0.04141233987211226,41.657997679721404],[0.04143147156724164,41.65800816296834],[0.04147856696939867,41.65803060300087],[0.0414794789205181,41.65803103718349],[0.04148032633097924,41.65803144119124],[0.0414911649706164,41.658036605282064],[0.041556750014081593,41.65806785553352],[0.04159884477250843,41.658084790331685],[0.04174148968556461,41.65813502391859],[0.04178860185152899,41.658147315142145],[0.041837880739592354,41.65815948147531],[0.04190665761197552,41.65818563888212],[0.04192652272367613,41.65819319433007],[0.04199795917409414,41.6582092632776],[0.04205417995477795,41.658222021373206],[0.04212590725725336,41.65823829819192],[0.04219359029120745,41.658253657192205],[0.04219840653305688,41.658254578363426],[0.042251606475657615,41.65826475147992],[0.04233834912036951,41.658281340105475],[0.042386751261308864,41.658289070735236],[0.042434450998720584,41.65828327464885],[0.04244071647171477,41.658280066056136],[0.042449364919922634,41.658275636220026],[0.04246224203853262,41.658269040500016],[0.042466747311755856,41.65826276832152],[0.0424715836701741,41.658256035138294],[0.042481994832724024,41.65824154115046],[0.04248371396116697,41.65821447849808],[0.04249443776872383,41.65810614490769],[0.04251305816772927,41.658087623415156],[0.04252125650771001,41.6581165426592],[0.042528257073656144,41.658141238262004],[0.04252997201114726,41.65817721506892],[0.042525380404316214,41.65825391619305],[0.04252770805896568,41.6583269493961],[0.042530111988938565,41.65840236305979],[0.042517528236957085,41.65856888801639],[0.04251579402108752,41.65859183515411],[0.042511053216371136,41.658633764789016],[0.04250610789320516,41.65867749988601],[0.04254461184409927,41.65862743226083],[0.04255568350065848,41.658613035503095],[0.042704411161208815,41.65841963983965],[0.04389609658098795,41.656869663241935],[0.043987920335705304,41.65675023201109],[0.044215711140824024,41.656453861308336],[0.0448310778189348,41.65671995154588],[0.04495933435614909,41.65677541041151],[0.04496666852186133,41.656778585476644],[0.04500843722423537,41.656796666919234],[0.045306469220308614,41.65692552527713],[0.04549528584973728,41.65700716334251],[0.045545746586218266,41.657028981437776],[0.04558705093112892,41.65704683992175],[0.04568211848256698,41.65708794393916],[0.04574764988184867,41.65711627728814],[0.04576830792163658,41.65712520904469],[0.04580129155077288,41.65713947001558],[0.0457895258725897,41.65711052897859],[0.04577522969768819,41.65705288411249],[0.04577237314491708,41.65699193174714],[0.04578172818760443,41.65692901801643],[0.045785033172221955,41.65690679256062],[0.04581981304331499,41.65687886908674],[0.045835246642544666,41.656861878968016],[0.04584914970616399,41.6568465727737],[0.04588982037915708,41.65681853027678],[0.045990798849064034,41.65676628251842],[0.04599208128032572,41.656765130006676],[0.04599548600959694,41.65676206893548],[0.046000725537581784,41.656757359143796],[0.04600219404710496,41.65675603899396],[0.046002961829481236,41.65675534916326],[0.04600879479624598,41.656750106282544],[0.04615034335630198,41.656622871499366],[0.0461992794245052,41.656603146365455],[0.04624594567319427,41.656588406787876],[0.0464349617919303,41.65653842214354],[0.046531061155710284,41.65650883318537],[0.04661638809689212,41.65647059158803],[0.04672136557304057,41.65639124848792],[0.04680226351632258,41.6563395639935],[0.04681761497289628,41.656332575162224],[0.046844204885912226,41.65632047001694],[0.04693414019773245,41.65628648894125],[0.04697996238872184,41.65627181725705],[0.047126162067124965,41.656236401199465],[0.04721121408186638,41.65619364846165],[0.0472491547688338,41.65617012883993],[0.04725368099681621,41.65616549113261],[0.04733935830157151,41.65607770745547],[0.04737087928851719,41.65602779405734],[0.0473798764239178,41.65601354733565],[0.0473980157016525,41.65598699178841],[0.04742684945028122,41.655944779683324],[0.04744455622178651,41.65592366063885],[0.04745390204437982,41.655912514383346],[0.04748784204872501,41.65588456827834],[0.04752534939127262,41.655852121091016],[0.047538546698602836,41.6558445078079],[0.04756629666708687,41.65582849753369],[0.04761112476430087,41.655809297107],[0.04765050797689009,41.65578572384109],[0.047725545293125234,41.65573875165293],[0.04775933023225249,41.65570629859829],[0.04778409540483924,41.655674153997694],[0.04780185246776655,41.65563768684939],[0.047806942797866035,41.65561827519866],[0.04781190739941044,41.65561704138247],[0.04781096359705707,41.6556121924512],[0.04783401467034309,41.655517336961935],[0.04786700165224085,41.6554508089543],[0.047859350650569836,41.655290596409316],[0.04779664311463493,41.65510650968815],[0.04767336794277238,41.65501912079867],[0.04745843833064664,41.654971486440076],[0.04732087117483444,41.654951105003136],[0.047169374133311154,41.6549079080244],[0.04712811924163216,41.65490965481308],[0.047008370336644074,41.6549907941552],[0.04684413950706359,41.65506236890701],[0.04678805702779036,41.655060926381395],[0.046692642465540314,41.655019170251876],[0.04661758922368819,41.654941443182764],[0.04660133084513729,41.654887686681775],[0.0466046643282273,41.654814781721825],[0.046499787434922904,41.65457065710103],[0.04650519292460042,41.654534300593866],[0.046667114539719494,41.65451319915135],[0.046984142444082645,41.65453819566446],[0.047065498877495456,41.65455993832262],[0.047178475204317276,41.65470882356297],[0.047246051788094746,41.65478635784831],[0.04724850852406075,41.654814494222535],[0.04725853244266107,41.65481555537153],[0.04725382432736899,41.654811863981166],[0.047251745615258536,41.6548102345391],[0.04728646094569332,41.654799684236934],[0.04731677158574888,41.65479047252478],[0.04736320900846773,41.65477777226437],[0.04740797256502346,41.65476552965586],[0.04742911591703391,41.65476109981975],[0.04747934698935431,41.65475057633972],[0.04749266751066849,41.65474778600395],[0.047493383325242,41.65474763596788],[0.04749877624206401,41.654746506087264],[0.04755576648150482,41.6547345669037],[0.04760358356556794,41.65472464692073],[0.04760559186968755,41.654724230340065],[0.04761344487523703,41.65472404929099],[0.047614034961255484,41.65472403587992],[0.0476151380197786,41.654724009896],[0.04761622850544622,41.65472398475029],[0.04762048735070153,41.654723886682035],[0.04762115119747228,41.6547238715946],[0.0476230496986538,41.65472382800871],[0.04762590708961529,41.654723761791644],[0.0478007703640026,41.65471006492285],[0.04784846255770102,41.65470435684648],[0.04789396204539906,41.65469408901447],[0.04793521693707806,41.65467947935636],[0.04802098644277373,41.654636745058696],[0.04802561912093276,41.65463492953836],[0.048070382677488484,41.654617391243136],[0.04811936484616189,41.654607123411154],[0.04815142730408473,41.65460315290338],[0.04816573772822247,41.65460138013074],[0.048209999208748286,41.654586668213426],[0.0482446240146234,41.6545796123269],[0.048337147658297275,41.654560757234606],[0.04849303849372496,41.654521229015074],[0.04849366881288103,41.6545210689207],[0.04849580955107865,41.65452052661152],[0.048506965864864936,41.65451811178508],[0.04848377313740689,41.65450714406413],[0.04846406644368568,41.65449782674],[0.04835557694989901,41.65444649680012],[0.048056706763458655,41.65431729394601],[0.047935193467747765,41.65426476287928],[0.04789959384647571,41.65424928150321],[0.047679226055248145,41.6541534461694],[0.04758604107937462,41.6541131971062]]]
> ]}}

saved as poly1.json

Is there any way to save them separately, I would like the final result to be an like this:
array = [coordinates of polygon 1], [coordinates of polygon 2] where in the case of using more polygons than in the example, they will be saved automatically without having to change the code, array = [coordinates of polygon 1], [coordinates of polygon 2],[coordinates of polygon 3] and so on.

So far i have this :

```
     require 'rubygems'
     require 'json'
     file = File.read('poly1.json')
     coordinates = JSON.parse(file)
     string=coordinates.to_s[0...-4]
     path = string.split"["
     path.shift()
     path.shift()
     path.shift()
```

This just gets all coordinates from both polygons in path. But what i want is to get polygon 1 coordinates separated from polygon 2 coordinates and in a case where i use a 3 polygon file, to get it separated whit out doing manualy.

Sorry for my bad english, and if you need something else ask in comments.

Comment: when you have your coordinates as a `JSON`, why do you convert it to a string?

Comment: i was trying to get last characters out and separate it in a array to make 2 different polygons. But spickerman give me a solution arleady.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is quite big and therefore not easy to understand. But from key structure at the beginning of the file

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[ [[[0.03990083369766674,41.65117297365802], ...
```

it looks like the `coordinates` are a simple hash nested below the `geometry` key. Therefore I would try the following:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

file = File.read('poly1.json')
data = JSON.parse(file)

coordinates = data["geometry"]["coordinates"]
coordinates[0]      #=> should now return the first coordonate from the array
```